# Descobrir quantos dias passaram de uma data até outra

Tags: java

Em um programa em java, onde a pessoa insere primeiro o dia, depois o mes, depois o ano, como faço para saber quantos dias passaram dessa data inserida até outra data posterior que também será informada pela pessoa?
Por exemplo:
Primeira data informada: 20/10/1990
Segunda data informada: 23//05/2005
Como faço para saber a quantidade total de dias que passaram?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [Date-Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) do Java 8 facilitou muito esse tipo de operação.

Para o seu problema em específico podemos nos valer das unidades [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html). O método [`between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) faz exatamente o que você está querendo.

```
LocalDate begin = LocalDate.of(1990, Month.OCTOBER, 20);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2005, Month.MAY, 23);
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(begin, end); // 5329
```

---

#### [Exemplo funcional no Ideone](http://ideone.com/I7wchb)

Answer (score 1):

Solução a partir do Java 1.4 focado no seu problema:

```
String dataUm = "20/10/1990";
String dataDois = "23/05/2005";

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // dd/MM/yyyy é o formato brasileiro que você está usando, para mais formatos, veja o link de referência

Date dateUm = simpleDateFormat.parse(dataUm);
Date dateDois = simpleDateFormat.parse(dataDois);

long diferencaEmMilisegundos = dateDois.getTime() - dateUm.getTime();

/**
 * divide por 1000 para converter em segundos
 * divide por 60 para converter em minutos 
 * divide por 60 novamente para converter em horas
 * divide por 24 para converter em dias
 */
System.out.println(diferencaEmMilisegundos / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
```

- [Link para visualizar os formatos de SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Boa. Esqueci de dizer, para o Java 5 ou superior temos a biblioteca [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Com ela o código encurta para [`Days.between(begin, end).getDays()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-).

Comment: Também podemos utilizar [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) para evitar conversões manuais: `TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diferencaEmMilisegundos, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`.

Comment: Joda-time procede! Agora o TimeUnit só a partir do Java 5, e a constant DAYS só a partir do java 6 :)