# Calcular idade por dia, mes e ano

Tags: java, data

Estou tentando calcular a idade por dia, mes e ano porém não estou conseguindo. Segui alguns exemplos mas todos dão errado também. Por exemplo se a data de nascimento é `14/06/1992` esse método retorna 23 anos e o correto seria 22, só seria 23 anos se a data de nascimento fosse maior ou igual a `15/06/1992`

```
public static int getIdade(java.util.Date dataNasc) {

        Calendar dateOfBirth = new GregorianCalendar();

        dateOfBirth.setTime(dataNasc);

        // Cria um objeto calendar com a data atual

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Obtém a idade baseado no ano

        int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dateOfBirth.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        dateOfBirth.add(Calendar.YEAR, age);

        // se a data de hoje é antes da data de Nascimento, então diminui 1.

        if (today.before(dateOfBirth)) {

            age--;

        }

        return age;

    }
```

Comment: dão errado em que sentido? quais os erros que são apresentados?

Comment: Da errado pois a idade exibida é incorreta, por exemplo. `14/06/1992` = 22 anos. O Resultado desse método é 23, seria 23 se a data de nascimento fosse maior ou igual a `15/06/1992`

Comment: Isso não está diretamente relacionado à sua pergunta, mas eu trocaria a assinatura da função pra `getIdade(java.util.Date dataNasc, java.util.Date hoje = null)` e `if (hoje == null) { Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(); } else { Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar(); today.setTime(hoje); }`: desse jeito, é possível escrever testes automáticos para a sua função (você passaria um dia de “hoje” fixo pra sua função nos testes).

Comment: Veja [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59862/100). A classe [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) também suporta `YEARS` e `MONTHS`. Finalmente, se você quiser computar os três de uma vez utilize o método [`Period.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#between-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalDate-).

Comment: Cálculo da idade em anos, meses e dias:<br>
http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/552949-idade-em-javafx-em-anos-meses-e-dias/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
public static int calculaIdade(java.util.Date dataNasc) {

    Calendar dataNascimento = Calendar.getInstance();  
    dataNascimento.setTime(dataNasc); 
    Calendar hoje = Calendar.getInstance();  

    int idade = hoje.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dataNascimento.get(Calendar.YEAR); 

    if (hoje.get(Calendar.MONTH) < dataNascimento.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
      idade--;  
    } 
    else 
    { 
        if (hoje.get(Calendar.MONTH) == dataNascimento.get(Calendar.MONTH) && hoje.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < dataNascimento.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
            idade--; 
        }
    }

    return idade;
}
```

}

Podes executar da seguinte forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
   {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
      Date dataNascimento = sdf.parse("15/11/1979"); 
      int idade = calculaIdade(dataNascimento);
      //A idade é:
      System.out.println(idade);
   }
```

Comment: Seu método não deveria retornar alguma coisa? Talvez também fosse uma boa acrescentar um exemplo de como se deve chamar o método `calculaIdade()` corretamente.

Comment: Tens toda a razão. Atualizado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, já consegui implementar.

Answer (score 6):

Antes de mais nada, o uso de classes como `java.util.Date` e `java.util.Calendar` devem ser evitadas, sendo alternativas classes da biblioteca [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) ou classes como `LocalDate` e `LocalDateTime`, além do restante da API de data e hora [`java.time`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) presente a partir do Java 8.

Usando a API do Java 8, mencionada acima, podemos usar a classe [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) para calcular o intervalo de tempo entre duas datas, inclusive a quantidade de anos. Assim, uma possível implementação de uma rotina seria como a seguir:

```
public static int idade(final LocalDate aniversario) {
    final LocalDate dataAtual = LocalDate.now();
    final Period periodo = Period.between(aniversario, dataAtual);
    return periodo.getYears();
}
```

A data é do tipo `LocalDate`, objeto que contém apenas data, não contém hora e não apresenta os problemas de fuso-horário da classe `java.util.Date`.

O método `Period#between` calcula o período entre a data de aniversário e a data atual criada com `LocalDate#now`.

Finalmente, a rotina retorna o número de anos do período.

Depois de entender como o método funciona, poderíamos abreviá-lo sem as variáveis auxiliares da seguinte forma:

```
public static int idade(final LocalDate aniversario) {
    return Period.between(aniversario, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
}
```

Se, por alguma razão, o programa precisa usar variáveis distintas para dia, mês e ano, basta aplicar `LocalDate.of` para criar uma data à partir dos valores e reusar a rotina acima:

```
public static int idade(final int dia, final int mes, final int ano) {
    return idade(LocalDate.of(ano, mes, dia));
}
```

Se, por uma outra razão, o programa precisa usar datas do tipo `java.util.Date`, podemos realizar a conversão para o tipo `LocalDate` e, mais uma vez, reusar a rotina mais acima:

```
public static int idade(final Date dataAniversario) {
    return idade(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(dataAniversario.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate());
}
```

Mais uma vez lembro que a insistência em usar `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar` e classes associadas, como a `SimpleDateFormat` e `DateFormat` frequentemente levam a problemas na manipulação e cálculo de datas devido a problemas de fuso-horário. Isto faz com que em períodos afetados pelo horário de verão, por pelo menos uma hora, os aniversários tenham o valor incorreto. fora outros problemas mais graves ao somar e subtrair tempo.

Comment: Excelente resposta @utluiz, tinha até me esquecido do fuso horário.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Idade {
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    public int idade;
    public final int anoatual= calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
    public final int mesatual = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
    public final int diaatual = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
    public int anoNasc;
    public int mesNsac;
    public int diaNasc;

    public Idade(int diaNasc, int mesNsac, int anoNasc ) {
        this.diaNasc = diaNasc;
        this.mesNsac = mesNsac;
        this.anoNasc = anoNasc;
    }

    public void calculandoIdade() {
       Date data = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println(data);

        System.out.println("                                          Data:"+this.diaatual+"/"+(this.mesatual+1)+"/"+this.anoatual);
        if (this.diaNasc>31 || this.mesNsac > 12 || this.diaatual>31 || this.mesatual > 12){
            System.out.println("Você digitou alguma data errada confira novamente!");
                    }else{System.out.println("Você nasceu em: "+this.diaNasc+"/"+this.mesNsac+"/"+this.anoNasc);}

        if (this.diaNasc>31 || this.mesNsac > 12 || this.diaatual>31 || this.mesatual > 12){
            System.out.println("Você digitou alguma data errada confira novamente!");
          }else if(this.mesNsac < this.mesatual ){
            this.idade = this.anoNasc - this.anoatual;
            System.out.println("Idade: "+this.idade+" anos");
        }else if (this.mesNsac > this.mesatual){
            this.idade = this.anoatual - this.anoNasc - 1;
            System.out.println("Idade: "+this.idade+" anos");
      }else if (this.mesNsac == this.mesatual && this.diaNasc == this.diaatual ){
            this.idade = this.anoatual - this.anoNasc;
            System.out.println("Idade: "+this.idade+" anos");
            System.out.println("Parabens!! Feliz Aniversário");
        }else if(this.mesNsac == this.mesatual && this.diaNasc < this.diaatual){
            this.idade = this.anoatual - this.anoNasc - 1;
            System.out.println("Idade: "+this.idade+" anos");
        }else if(this.mesNsac == this.mesatual && this.diaNasc > this.diaatual){
            this.idade = this.anoatual - this.anoNasc;

     };
   }
}
```