# Calcular idade pegando uma data do tipo Date

Tags: java, data, java-8

Eu gostaria de calcular a idade pegando a data de nascimento vindo do banco de dados, através do `pojo`.

Estava olhando como fazer um calculo de datas, olhando esta pergunta: [Calcular idade por dia, mes e ano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69270/calcular-idade-por-dia-mes-e-ano)

Minha data no banco esta como `DATE`, então eu não consegui converter para poder comparar com  localDate, resulta este erro:

> (incompatible types: Date cannot be converted to LocalDate)

Eu estava tentando fazer assim:

```
 public int idade() {
    return Period.between(meuPojo.getDataNascimento(), LocalDate.now()).getYears();
}
```

meu método do pojo que pega a data (`getDataNascimento()`) é do tipo `java.util.Date`;

Como faço essa conversão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você armazena a data no formato `util.Date`, precisa antes converter para o tipo [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), que é o equivalente ao `util.Date` no pacote [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Porém, assim como `Date`, `Instant` representa um ponto no tempo, mas sem informação de fuso, e para converter para `LocalDate`, precisa dessa informação. Então você informa um [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)(uma representação do fuso de determinada região), pegando o fuso do sistema em execução, para depois converter para `LocalDate`:

```
Date birthday = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("03/09/1990");

LocalDate ldirthday = birthday.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

System.out.println(Period.between(ldirthday, LocalDate.now()).getYears());
```

Testando na mesma data de publicação desta resposta, resultou em:

> 26

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/Jedvxc).

No caso do seu método, ficaria assim:

```
 public int idade() {

    LocalDate ldirthday = meuPojo.getDataNascimento().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    return Period.between(ldirthday, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
}
```

Recomendo a leitura [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177130/28595) sobre conversão e utilização de classes de datas do novo pacote `java.time`, que dá uma explicação bastante abrangente sobre o tema.

---

**Referencia**:

[Best way to convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate in Java 8 - Examples](http://www.java67.com/2016/12/best-way-to-convert-javautildate-to-javatime-LocalDate-in-Java8.html)

[Como migrar de Date e Calendar para a nova API de datas no Java 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177129/como-migrar-de-date-e-calendar-para-a-nova-api-de-datas-no-java-8)

Comment: aqui ele não deixou usar o toLocalDate, sera que é porque o método getDataNascimento é java.util.Date ?

Comment: @G.Araujo na pergunta você disse que era java.sql.Date.

Comment: no banco é Date, mas eu digo o metodo. É bom editar a pergunta?

Comment: @G.Araujo com certeza, a falta dessa informação induziu minha resposta.

Comment: editei a pergunta !

Comment: @G.Araujo resposta atualizada.